# Updating Laravel Pivot (BelongsToMany) Table using Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have my VueJs form like this with v-model

```
<select name="service_id" v-model="client.services[0].pivot.service_id">
     <option v-for="service in services" v-bind:key="service.id" v-bind:value="service.id">
      {{ service.company_name }}
      </option>
 </select>
```

and i am sending the data in json using `return Client::with('services')->find($clientd);` with belongsToMany in my Client and Service Model with `clients_services` as pivot table.

I am having problem updating the form because i keep getting `The service id field is required.`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `v-model` and `:value` must be changed.

try with `v-model="service_id"` and `:value="client.services[0].pivot.service_id"`